# [AS3][Air for Android] Get streaming mic input?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there a way to get true mic streaming input?

The example code I have at the moment looks to be getting the mic input data, and saving it to a sound object and playing it right away.

Is there a way to stream it properly?

If not, in my example, is there a way to get the mic input data, but mute the audio, as it is causing a feedback loop (despite setLoopBack being set to false..)

Code below:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.utils.*;

var _soundBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var _micBytes:ByteArray;
var son:Sound;
var sc:SoundChannel;
var pow:int = 0;
var myBar:Sprite;

stage.quality = "LOW";

// this code ended up muting the mic input oddly?
//SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);

init();

function init()
{
    myBar = new Sprite;
    micInit();
    soundInit();

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, visualise);
}

function micInit()
{
    var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

    if(mic != null) {
        //mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
        mic.setLoopBack(false);
        mic.setSilenceLevel(0);
        mic.rate = 44;
        mic.gain = 60;
        mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
    }
}

function micSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    _micBytes = event.data;
    sc = son.play();
}

function soundInit():void {
    son = new Sound();
    son.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, soundSampleDataHandler);
}

function soundSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192 && _micBytes.bytesAvailable > 0; i++) {
        var sample:Number = _micBytes.readFloat();
        event.data.writeFloat(sample);
        event.data.writeFloat(sample);
    }
}

function drawLines(e:Event):void{

    SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(_soundBytes, true);
    myBar.graphics.clear();
    myBar.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xabc241);
    for (var i=0; i < 256; i++) {
        pow = _soundBytes.readFloat()*200;
        pow = Math.abs(pow);
        myBar.graphics.drawRect(i*2, 0, 2, pow);
        addChild(myBar);
    }
}
```

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 2):

To use acoustic echo cancellation, call Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone() to get a reference to an enhanced Microphone object. Set the Microphone.enhancedOptions property to an instance of the MicrophoneEnhancedOptions class.  Here is an article that discusses it all.  [Article about enhanced microphone options at Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/acoustic-echo-cancellation.html)

EDIT:  I spoke too soon.  I have used enhanced mic many times before, but I decided to read the article myself to see if there were any interesting things I could learn new from it... and I found this near the end

AEC is computationally expensive. Currently, only desktop platforms are supported for Flash Player and AIR

Although I just looked at the date... last year, so maybe give it a try and it is supported now?!?

Comment: Apologies for being dumb, but how will this potentially help me? (lets just say it works on Android)

Comment: you said you were trying to hack around the bad feedback issue.  That is what the acoustic echo cancellation with enhancedMicrophone resolves.

Comment: here... this app does what you are trying to do (records the audio also)... it has the fxp you can download also [Sample App](http://coenraets.org/blog/air-for-android-samples/voice-notes-for-android/)

Comment: The sample app was a huge insight, thank you! Turns out I don't need to use the Sound Spectrum, instead you can interact with the microphone activity level directly in the Sample Data Handler. My issues now are trying to get all my numbers to match up in terms of mic gain, sample rate and animation speeds etc etc